# How to get the same result array when querying laravel table

Tags: php, laravel

When using laravel built in laravel model methods returns a list of result array. But when querying the same table getting different object. Please check the below code - how can I get the same result set?

```
$users = User::all();

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [email] => amirtha@gmail.com
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [email] => renjith@123.com

        )
    )
```

But when using the sql query like the below:

```
$result = DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.id','u.email','u.role','u.created_at')
            ->join('roles as r','r.id','=','u.role')
            ->where('u.role', '!=',  1 )
            ->orderBy('u.name','asc')
            ->get();
            print_r($result);
```

I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\User Object
        (
            [fillable:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => name
                [1] => email
                [2] => password
                [3] => lastname
                [4] => mobile
                [5] => role
            )

            [hidden:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => password
                [1] => remember_token
            )

            [casts:protected] => Array
            (
                 [email_verified_at] => datetime
            )

            [connection:protected] => mysql
            [table:protected] => users
            [primaryKey:protected] => id
            [keyType:protected] => int
            [incrementing] => 1
            [with:protected] => Array
            (
            )

            [withCount:protected] => Array
            (
            )

            [perPage:protected] => 15
            [exists] => 1
            [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            [attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => amritha
                [email] => amritha@gmail.com
            )
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Are you wanting the results as a collection of Eloquent modes?

Comment: larvel version 5.3

Comment: Do you have a `role` relationship set up in your `User` model?

Comment: i didnt set up a relationship in the user model , how can i set up the relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is when you want to use the table alias so what about this:

```
 $result =  User::query()->from('User as u')
            ->select('u.id','u.email','u.role','u.created_at')
            ->join('roles as r','r.id','=','u.role')
            ->where('u.role', '!=',  1 )
            ->orderBy('u.name','asc')
            ->get();
```

.

Comment: thank you , one doubt what is the difference in using User::query()->from('Users as u') VS DB::table('users as u')

Comment: @Osama Alvi the DB object queries the database in a raw format, which is prone for SQL injection, while using the eloquent improves your security for querying data :)

Comment: It's optional, it helps you to find the functions, like try remove query function and then check the function 'from' it will turn yellow.

Answer (score 0):

This query is the same with "SELECT * FROM USERS"
    $users = User::all();

While this one is different from the earlier query

```
$result = DB::table('users as u')
->select('u.id','u.email','u.role','u.created_at')
->join('roles as r','r.id','=','u.role')
->where('u.role', '!=',  1 )
->orderBy('u.name','asc')
->get();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: hi can i use $users = User::all(); where user role not equal to 1

Comment: how can integrate the where with User::all()

Comment: hello! :D i think the method that you're looking for is the Eloquent way for joining, you should create "relationships" first, please see Laravel docs for that, then you may try this User::select('id', 'email', 'role', 'created_at)->has('roles')->orderBy('uname', 'asc')->get();